# Adb pull - access denied

Tags: adb

I want copy all files(including system files),
but when I enter adb pull /

i get this:[image]

I tried entering adb root but that does nothing.
[image]

Is there any fix to this?
Else any other way to copy all files(including files like /data) to my pc?

PS:I have rooted my phone(OnePlus 6t) and have twrp and magisk.

Thanks

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94533/discussion-on-question-by-helper-adb-pull-access-denied).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To (re-)enable `adb root` you have to modify your `prop.default` file. This file was traditionally named `default.prop` and stored inside the ramdisk of `boot.img` - however, for [system-as-root](https://source.android.com/devices/bootloader/system-as-root) devices it is inside `/vendor`.

change the line `ro.build.type=eng` into:

```
ro.build.type=userdebug
```

from the Magisk Troubleshoot Wiki:

> **ADB cannot run as root in production builds**
>
> If you're having issues running the ADB root command after installing Magisk this is because of MagiskHide setting a few prop values to known "safe" values. You can get ADB root working again by turning of MagiskHide and rebooting, but if you need MagiskHide for some app or service this could quickly become annoying.
>
> A more convenient solution is to reset `ro.build.type` and `ro.debuggable` to their original values (`userdebug` and `1` respectively). This can be done by using the Magisk resetprop tool (see the [Magisk Documentation](https://topjohnwu.github.io/Magisk/details.html#resetprop) for details), either by running it directly in a terminal emulator, in a late_start service [boot script](https://topjohnwu.github.io/Magisk/guides.html#boot-scripts), or by using the [MagiskHide Props Config](https://forum.xda-developers.com/apps/magisk/module-magiskhide-props-config-t3789228) Magisk module's "Edit [MagiskHide](https://www.didgeridoohan.com/magisk/MagiskHide) props" function.